# Android PWA what do I do with my manifest and service workers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app that I want to notify users to download when viewing on Android. I used PWA Builder to build my service workers and manifest: https://www.pwabuilder.com/

I now have a manifest file, do I just upload this to my root directory?

manifest:

```
{
    "dir": "ltr",
    "lang": "en",
    "name": "Seek Adventure",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "browser",
    "start_url": "https://www.seekadventure.net/",
    "short_name": "SeekAdventure",
    "theme_color": "#ff8040",
    "description": "An #optoutside forum for anyone looking for help planning there next outdoor adventure or wants to share their adventures with others!",
    "orientation": "any",
    "background_color": "transparent",
    "related_applications": [],
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/images/assets/favicon-glzu44cb.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "64x64"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/c52cd81f-b772-8db2-4964-5780e9748729.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "44x44",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/3fd8d17f-4da0-000c-0914-88f09a62a071.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/fdf7841f-c005-e322-4e41-d9b997beb0d2.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "1240x600",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/1b53345e-9214-10f9-3b27-d9a11d1a6362.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "300x300",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/dc7a39e4-e3ad-9489-5fe1-65f029c4f5a8.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "150x150",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/934dcf12-e11d-2f60-17a4-cf7529240c69.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "88x88",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/85b5b747-256b-049a-425b-f8d57c110834.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "24x24",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/0f323aec-4450-d0c3-623c-f35c9edcdd08.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "50x50",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/03236d66-5cdf-a8a6-73f9-ecfe05b08fcc.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "620x300",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/2a1f7b69-0b45-32d9-ec15-a9ec2de16a35.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/5585e3aa-2696-082b-804b-f087d8923570.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/c1943668-4dcf-fe5b-6ae4-a6ebc4f9f99b.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/f37abd30-b572-4008-f307-8c0c674972ec.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/737282cf-e911-bd86-39dc-87b45b7a3a5b.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "36x36",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/dd79a596-ca4f-6a28-9c00-8b8038a8fa88.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/3be7d34f-ba7b-ecb5-579d-467cacd866c4.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "180x180",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/51578c8b-2898-5b6c-f935-21dea3f1cbf5.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/535b042a-2502-3835-765b-923293ac8bbd.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "120x120",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/f0ab6a28-2fdd-3ca9-6882-5d512562629d.webPlatform.png",
            "sizes": "76x76",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

It also gave me a couple service worker files below.

pwabuilder-sw.js:

```
//This is the "Offline page" service worker

//Install stage sets up the offline page in the cache and opens a new cache
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  var offlinePage = new Request('offline.html');
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch(offlinePage).then(function(response) {
      return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
        console.log('[PWA Builder] Cached offline page during Install'+ response.url);
        return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
      });
  }));
});

//If any fetch fails, it will show the offline page.
//Maybe this should be limited to HTML documents?
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function(error) {
      console.error( '[PWA Builder] Network request Failed. Serving offline page ' + error );
      return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match('offline.html');
      });
    }
  ));
});

//This is a event that can be fired from your page to tell the SW to update the offline page
self.addEventListener('refreshOffline', function(response) {
  return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function(cache) {
    console.log('[PWA Builder] Offline page updated from refreshOffline event: '+ response.url);
    return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
  });
});
```

pwabuilder-sw-register.js:

```
//This is the "Offline page" service worker

//Add this below content to your HTML page, or add the js file to your page at the very top to register service worker
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
  console.log('[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register')
} else {
  //Register the ServiceWorker
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('pwabuider-sw.js', {
    scope: './'
  }).then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered for scope:'+ reg.scope);
  });
}
```

If the manifest gets uploaded to the root of my web server do I also upload these two javascript files to the root also?

If so do I just edit the header in my html files and include these two lines to point to the javascript files?

```
<script src="pwabuilder-sw.js"></script> 
<script src="pwabuilder-sw-register.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can put the manifest to the root directory to show it in every app page or you can put it only in the path you want showing it.

About the last question, if you need to add the .js files to your server make sure they aren't in the same place where are the other .js files.

Comment: why can't they be in a directory with other javascript?